# Is it possible to get any server logs in a container's var/log?

Tags: docker

In client server, configured rsyslog.conf to send remote log messages using UDP.

```
@docker_host_IP:514
```

Then, Restarted Rsyslog :

```
service rsyslog restart
```

In container server, configured the `rsyslog.conf` to get the remote logs by  uncommenting the following lines to make your server to listen on the udp -

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

And passed the IP of the docker host while running the container.

But Still not able to get the logs of the server to inside the container . What is my mistake ? And what needs to be done ?